# Send base64 image chooses from gallery to server in Ionic3

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am using camera and image pickers plugins to add functionality to add photos using camera and gallery. But while I am selecting images from gallery and trying to send to server, as base64 image I am not able to get it server end. It sends an empty string.

```
add.dog.ts.
//Open image picker multiple images
  openImagePicker(){
let options = {
  maximumImagesCount: 3,
}
this.photos = new Array<string>();
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
.then((results) => {
  this.reduceImages(results).then(() => {        
    for (let index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {          
        this.photos.push(results[index]);  
        this.base64.encodeFile(results[index]).then((base64File: string) => {
        this.pic = base64File;
        this.authService.uploadPhotosServer(this.pic).then((result) => {
        this.responseData = result;  
  }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      }
    //console.log("Image Lists", this.photos);
  });
}, (err) => { console.log(err) });

 }
```

So here I am sending `this.pic = base64File` to services where I am sending post request to server like this.

```
  uploadPhotosServer(photos){ //console.log(photos);
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let datafile = photos;
     this.http.post(uploadDogPhotosGalleryAuthEndPoint,datafile, {headers: headers})
  .subscribe(res => {
    resolve(res.json());
  }, (err) => {
    resolve(err.json());
  });
 });
}
```

And server side I am trying to access the data like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {        
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);die;
  }
```

But it prints empty always. If I check console it displays request payload like:

```
data:image/*;charset=utf-8;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($postData )
```